# Problems creating Comunity page on napili template (Salesforce Customer Community)

Tags: community, customer-community, lightning-design-system

Dears,
I have been trying to create a community page on napili template, but no success so far I set the page and have this error:
[image: Error]

If I take the : out from the arguments, leaving it as /case/objectName/filterId, it accepts and creates the menu Item, but when I click on it, It takes to the error page. Any Ideas on how to work that out? Best Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace the ":objectName" and the ":filterId" with the desired parameter values.
Your URL should then look like this: /case/Case/[ListviewId]

An example:
The ListviewId you can find within your salesforce URL when you load a listview created in your ORG:

> https://eu11.salesforce.com/500?fcf=**00B0Y000003GF0a**

Hope this helps.